# No output in word count program in C

Tags: c

I am a new learner of C language. I recently got to know about the **getchar()** function. I wrote a program to count number of words in an input. The program goes as follows: (I AM USING CODEBLOCKS):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
int c, nw;       /*nw stands for NUMBER OF WORDS*/

while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
    if (c==' '||c=='\t'||c=='\n')
        ++nw; 
}

printf("NUMBER OF WORDS ARE:%d",nw);
}
```

When I run the program, it takes the input, but there is no OUTPUT. It just keeps on taking the input no matter how many times you press enter.

I tried to search for this a million times but I couldn't find the answer.

However, someone told me to include a Ctrl+D break in the while loop. I tried to do that but same result.

Please if someone has a solution help me. From past 2 weeks I am trying to figure out the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Change your cancelation condition to something different like 'q' or whatever

Comment: You need to initialize `nw` to zero, or else, you will get strange output.

Comment: ctrl-d for nix, ctrl-z for windows. Uninitialised `nw` will give wrong result though (addressed in Roy's answer).

Comment: 0) `nw` initialize to 0, `nw=0;` 1) add `\n`, printf("NUMBER OF WORDS ARE:%d\n", nw); 2) try enter then ctrl+d or ctrl+z then enter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop will end when it encounters `EOF`(-1).

> It just keeps on taking the input no matter how many times you press enter.

Because `'\n' != EOF`.

To stimulate `EOF`,

- Press <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> if you are using windows/DOS. This must be followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> if you are on UNIX/Linux/OSX. This flushes the `stdin` there are characters to be flushed. Otherwise, it sends `EOF` to the `stdin`.

---

BTW, as others have noticed, you need to initialize `nw` to 0. Also, the signature of `main` should be `int main(void)`.